# Trigger Spring argument mapping manually?

Tags: java, spring

I've a nicely working Spring argument mapping for my arguments, unfortunately I've one component which isn't passed through the DispatcherServlet and I struggle to find a way to get the mapping to run somehow manually.

An example would look like this:

```
public class Bar {
    public Bar(@RequestParam("map") String map) {
        System.out.println("Found: " + map); // Expected result "Found: value
    }
}
public class Foo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
          context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/context.xml");
          String pseudoUrl = "/?map=value"
          Bar bar = context.getBeans('bar', pseudoUrl);
   }
}
```

It that something which could work somehow? As you can imaging the passed around data has a more complex structure and therefore I'd like to avoid that I've to write an parser on my own.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You could basically follow the same algorithm that [`DispatcherServlet.doDispatch()` does](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/v3.1.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.servlet/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#L873):

1. for each `HandlerMapping` in the context, (line 1058 of DispatcherServlet in spring-webmvc.jar 3.1.2-RELEASE), test if `HandlerMapping.getHandler(request)` returns non-null
2. for each HandlerAdapter in the context, (line 1091) test if `HandlerAdapter.supports(handlerMapping)` returns true
3. execute `HandlerAdapter.handle(request, ...)` and handle the output (line 923)

This would require you to bundle up your pseudoUrl into a pseudo-HttpServletRequest, etc.

On the other hand, if you know that you always want to get a specific bean from the context in your `main()` method, I would just ask Spring for that bean and invoke the method explicitly, rather than dealing with mapping beans to a URL (which I assume does not change).

Comment: actually I was hoping to find sth. more lightweight :(

Comment: is the URL that you want to lookup constant?

Comment: nope - actually I'm in the middle of a SolrComponent and I'd like to extract some parts of the (search) request URL and pass that along into a small  part of my domain model ... that's why I have a URL without having a servlet context :/